# Behavior of Dynamically Created Buttons in HTML Becomes Dependent on the First Created

Tags: javascript, html, loops

I'm new working with javascripts. I have an condition that assigns values to a certain variable depending on a condition. The values contain commands that creates a button dynamically and displays it in a . Here is the code for that:

```
if (closure == "Closed") {
    newData = newData + "<br>" + (f + 1) + ". " + data[i + 10] + " - " + data[i] + "-" + data[i + 1] + " " + data[i + 4] + " at " + data[i + 3] + "<h3 align='right'><input type='button' value='Approve' class='button' onclick='conf(" + data[i + 11] + ")' /><br>DATE LAST UPDATED: " + data[1] + " <br>LAST UPDATED BY: " + data[i + 9] + " - " + data[i + 10] + "</h3>";
} else {
    newData = newData + "<br>" + (f + 1) + ". ";
}
```

This is within  a while loop. Upon clicking the button, it returns a value to a function. My problem is that the behavior of the first created button in that  is being inherited by the rest so when i remove the first button, all of the dynamically created buttons in that  are removed.

The code works well because it updates only the correct data in my database, however, there is a problem with the presence of those buttons.

Comment: I tried assigning an ID for each button created but it does not work

Comment: Finally it works, just a matter of using the right array index. thanks anyway